# Vertically align for-loops with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

Scientific code often features loop nests such as

```cpp
for(int x=0;x<10;x++)
for(int y=0;y<10;y++)
for(int z=0;z<10;z++){
  func(x, y, z);
}
```

The extra levels of indentation can pose a readability issue.

Does clang-format have a means of vertically aligning sequential for-loops if the outer loops don't have brackets?

Comment: I don't think there is. It is pretty easy to create entertaining bugs by adding a `;` at the end of one of the `for` lines so I'd advise against it anyways. You can always resort to a localized `// clang-format off` or create a old school macro if the pattern is so idiomatic in your context

Comment: If that’s a common pattern for you, you should write an function that takes the x, y, z ranges and a lambda to call for every combination.